# gitlab disable access over ip address

Tags: dns, ip-address, gitlab

I installed gitlab_7.3.2-omnibus-1_amd64 on Ubuntu 14.04.1.

I defined a domain name for gitlab and it works well. However, gitlab is still accessible over server's ip address. I want gitlab to be only accessible via domain name, not server's ip. Can you help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. Domain name resolves to IP on domain server, you always access server over IP.